# Unetbootin commands for installing ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unetbootin

I have made a live usb using unetbootin trying to install ubuntu 13.10
when i boot it up, the usual unetbootin start up screen appears, but when i choose any of the options, the screen goes smaller and a terminal type thing appears

I have also tried remaking the usb.

How do i install the os?

what are the commands to do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry i didn't say but im running ubuntu 12.04

Comment: In that case, use the Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu itself.

Comment: could you describe the text in the screen that is there once you select an option?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're running Ubuntu, you don't need to use Unetbootin. As minerz029 said, you can just use Startup Disk Creator. It should already be installed. 
To find it, press the Super key (looks like the Windows icon) and type in "Startup Disk Creator" at the top. 
 
Then, afterwards, everything should be pretty straightforward. Choose your usb, find your iso, specify how much space, then just let it install. It'll take a little bit.